# Update session variable when form is submited. AJAX. Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

What I want to do is when I submit my form with ticket code the variables should update without page refresh. What I only achieve now is submit form without page refresh and it works. And if I submit form and then refresh page manually the variables change, but then again I can submit the same form. So I want to prevent that. This is my form:

`Form`

```
 <form id="ticket" action="prekiu-uzsakymas" method="get">
                        <input type="text" name="ticket">
                        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Panaudoti kuponą">
                    </form>
```

This is my `AJAX`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#ticket').on('submit',function(e){
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault(e);


                $.ajax({

                    method:"GET",
                    url: $("#ticket").attr("action"),
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var statusHTML = '<h4><span class="label label-success">' +
                                '<i style="color: white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Ticket used successfuly.</span></h4><br>';

                        $("#ticket").replaceWith(statusHTML);
                    },
                    error:function(data){
                        console.log("request failed");
                    }
                })

            });

        });
```

This is what executes when I submit form with page refresh:

```
foreach ($products as &$item) {
                    $item['price'] = $item['price'] - ($item['price'] * ($ticket->discount / 100));
                }

                Session::put('cart', $products);
```

It all works but I don't know how to update values without page refresh so the user can see and cannot submit the form second time.

Comment: U cant do it. With sessions at least. If u explain what do u need to me, i can suggest the right way to achieve it.

Comment: I want to update price that is shown without page refresh when form is submited.

Comment: Then u should update it like `$('#price').text();`. If u need to do it with array of products u need to create function, which will clear all data and repopulate it. Its much easier if u use things like AngularJs

Comment: Okay, is there are any alternative when form is submited do not let it submit again after page refresh ?

Comment: You need to use something like cookies or html 5 cache to save user action and add check it before form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your form in a session variable check.

`form`

```
   @if ( !request()->session()->get('ticket') )
       <form id="ticket" action="prekiu-uzsakymas" method="POST">
           <input type="text" name="ticket">
           <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Panaudoti kuponą">
       </form>
   @else
        <h4>
            <span class="label label-success">
                <i style="color: white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Ticket used successfully.
            </span>
        </h4>
        <br>
   @endif
```

This prevents the form from being displayed if a discount ticket has been stored in the session.

Then set this in your code along with the cart contents:

```
   // Check for ticket being sent in request, then check the session to make sure it's not set
   if ( request()->input('ticket') && (!request()->session()->get('ticket') ) ) {

       foreach ($products as &$item) {
           $item['price'] = $item['price'] - ($item['price'] * ($ticket->discount / 100));
       }

       Session::put('cart', $products);
       Session::put('ticket', request()->input('ticket'));
   }

   // Return your altered products in your response,
   // so you can update the info presented to the user
   return response()->json(['products' => $products]);
```

In your `JavaScript/AJAX`:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
           }
       });

       $('#ticket').on('submit',function(e){

           e.preventDefault();

           $.ajax({

               method: $("#ticket").attr("method"),
               url: $("#ticket").attr("action"),
               data:$(this).serialize(),
               dataType: 'html',
               success: function(data) {
                   var statusHTML = '<h4><span class="label label-success">' +
                           '<i style="color: white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Ticket used successfully.</span></h4><br>';

                   $("#ticket").replaceWith(statusHTML);

                   // data will now contain your products with updated prices
                   // You can access this with: data.products
                   // Example:
                   if (data.products) {
                       $(data.products).each( function(index) {
                           $("#product-"+$(this).id).find(".price").html($(this).price);
                       });
                   }
               },
               error: function(data){
                   console.log("request failed");
               }
           })

       });

   });
```

I've also modified the form method to be POST, which is optional. If you go with this, you need to change the route for this in your routes.php to be `Route::post`. Otherwise, you can use GET.

Comment: Thanks for you effort! I'm getting this error now: `prekiu-uzsakymas:263 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined` in this line: dataType: 'html',

Comment: Hey mate! I did it with refresh! The thing that I needed most was the store used ticket in the session! Thanks!

Comment: Can u somehow invite me to chat ? I've one more question

Comment: I've added a check to see if "products" were returned in the response. I can't see the entirety of your project, so only you know what $products contains and what gets passed back through the AJAX response. You could also try using `success: function(response)` and then change `if (data.products)` to `if (response.products)`.